# How add certificate to LinkedIn profile with api or with other methods?

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

To update LinkedIn design I added certificates with link:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add
    ?_ed=<token>
    &pfCertificationName=<name>
    &pfCertificationUrl=<url>
    &pfLicenseNo=<licenseNo>
    &pfCertStartDate=201703
    &trk=<value>
```

How I can add certificate now?